# Cavity map generation

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm how to generate cavity (or curvature) map. There seems to be no refernce to it, only final solutions like xNormal software, but that is not what I want. I am looking for a way how to do it, not for a final solution.

I have also found this site: http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Curvature_map, but again, mostly references how to do it in specified soft (maya etc).

On my input, I have a mesh and a normal map. From this, I have calculated curvature on my mesh, and now I would like to extend this info with more details from normal map.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the polygon surface to the surface at the end of its normals (or a small factor of)

[image]

Calculating it with a normal map is similar. iterate over the polygon using the normal map's texels.